# Joomla Error Unable to find install package

Tags: iis, joomla, multilingual

I need to install language pack bud get this error message:

Error Unable to find install package

This happened when I used Install button directly from availavle language list. Then I tried to install it from tmp folder with xml and zip files but get following error:
Warning

Install path does not exist.
Package Install: There was an error installing an extension: site_sk-SK.zip
Error

Error installing package

Windows server 2012
IIS 8.5
PHP 5.6
Joomla 3.8.1

Of course, I set folder and file permissions acoording to this guide https://docs.joomla.org/IIS

I'm very disappointed. Can somebody find a solution how to install language pack?

Comment: Your `tmp` and `log` path needs to be rechecked. check in your control panel the path to your website.

Comment: I checked and the paths exist and has write permissions. Should be slashes or backslashes in the path? Does it matter?

Answer (score 2):

This error always comes down to a permission issue, Joomla is unable to write/read from the `tmp` folder. Make sure that your `tmp` folder that is defined in the `configuration.php` is fully writable.

I believe that even after fixing this problem, you will run into a different issue, as Joomla needs write permissions to most of its folders to install an extension, and if that write permission is not granted, then Joomla will not be able to install the extension.

Answer (score 0):

My fix is to chown the entire joomla folder to www-data.www-data (this is for Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

try command:

```
chown www-data:www-date /var/www/html/joomla
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While your code may be helpful, you need to clearly explain how it answers the question.

Comment: Probably should be `www-data:www-data`